# Set every nth bit in an integer without for loop

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Is there a way to set every nth bit in an integer without using a for loop?

For example, if `n = 3`, then the result should be `...100100100100`. This is easy enough with a for loop, but I am curious if this can be done without one.

--

For my particular application, I need to do this with a custom 256-bit integer type, that has all the bit operations that a built-in integer has. I'm currently using lazily initialized tables (using for loops) and that is good enough for what I'm doing. This was mostly an exercise in bit-twidling for me, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in a few steps/instructions, and couldn't easily find anything online about this.

Comment: Considering the are finite possibilities for POD types, how about a lookup table or just constants?

Comment: How many bits in the integer?  As mentioned, a simple lookup table would be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Added a few more details in the question body.

Comment: Well if you have a "custom" 256 bit integer type, the onus would be on you to figure it out because nobody else has any idea how it works, and would be able to determine if there's a loop-less approach. On the other hand, as everyone else has already mentioned, for native integer types a simple lookup table will do.

Comment: Look at numbers of the form (2^m-1)/(2^n-1).

Comment: If it is just 256 bits (and nothing unlimited like GNU MP), why not use an array with 256 items, ideally `constexpr` or otherwise prepared at compile time, where indices 1 through 255 would reference the expected bit-interleaved integers? That wouldn’t require a run-time for-cycle. It could be either just written “manually” (as in “let Bash write it”) or generated using `std::index_sequence` — C++ fold expressions could expand it nicely into an array initializer with the right bits and shifts, at compile time, perhaps using a small `constexpr` helper function.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks, `UINT256_MAX / ((1 << n) - 1)` was basically what I was looking for.

Comment: Why not use a loop and `consteval`/`constexpr`? Let the compiler optimize that down to a pre-computed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … I need to do this with a custom 256-bit integer type.

Set `r` to `256 % n`.

Set `d` to `((uint256_t) 1 << n) - 1`. Then the binary representation of `d` is a string of `n` 1 bits.

Set `t` to `UINT256_MAX << r >> r`. This removes the top `r` bits from `UINT256_MAX`. `UINT256_MAX` is of course 2<sup>256</sup>−1. This leaves `t` as a string of `width-r` 1 bits, and `width-r` is some multiple of `n`, say `k*n`.

Set `t` to `t/d`. As a string of `k*n` 1 bits divided by a string of `n` 1 bits, this produces a quotient that is `000…0001` repeated `k` times, where each `000…0001` is `n-1` 0 bits followed by one 1 bit.

Now `t` is the desired bit pattern except the highest desired bit may be missing if `r` is not zero. To add this bit, if needed, OR `t` with `t << n`.

Now `t` is the desired value.

Alternately:

Set `t` to 1.

OR `t` with `t << n`.

OR `t` with `t << 2*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 4*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 8*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 16*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 32*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 64*n`.

OR `t` with `t << 128*n`.

Those shifts must be defined (shifting by zero would suffice) or suppressed when the shift amount exceeds the integer width, 256 bits.

Comment: Seems like the first solution can be simplified into `UINT256_MAX / ((1 << n) - 1)`?

Comment: @abc: No, if `n` is not a factor of the width, there are high bits that mess up the quotient. Try it with 16 bits with n=3: `(1<<3)-1` is 7, `65535/7` is 9362, that is 10010010010010 in binary, but you want 1001001001001001.